# Elasticsearch compound query formation

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a JSON like this:

```json
[
 {
  "tenant_id": "012345",
  "status": "Active"
 },
 {
  "tenant_id": "012345",
  "status": "Not Applicable"
 },
 {
  "tenant_id": "012345",
  "status": "Inactive"
 }
]
```

I want to fetch all the documents from Elasticsearch which can be shown in the following representation:

1. `tenant_id` must match to a certain ID and
2. `status` can either be `Active` or `Not Applicable`

How to write a query for this?
I have tried with following query but it did not work:

```json
{
    "size": 2,
    "track_total_hits": true,
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "should": [
                {
                    "term": {
                        "status": "Active"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "term": {
                        "status": "Not Applicable"
                    }
                }
            ],
            "must": {
                "term": {
                    "tenant_id": "012345"
                }
            },
            "minimum_should_match" : 1
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need multiple `should` clauses with a minimum should match. You can use [terms](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-terms-query.html) for this. Terms takes an array of which one should match.

Since, both your conditions are mandatory you can wrap them in a `must`:

```
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must": [
                {
                    "terms": {
                        "status": ["Active","Not Applicable"]
                    }
                },
            {
                "term": {
                    "tenant_id": "012345"
                }
            }
          ]
        }
    }
```

Note : Term queries are for keyword fields and take in no analysis.

Comment: Thank you. It's returning `parsing_exception` with a reason as `[term] query does not support array of values`.

Comment: Typo. It is supposed to be terms. Check the answer.

Comment: I need to further add `status.keyword` to make it work. Thanks, @Tushar.

Comment: That will be the case if you are using multiple types for the same field but yes the idea is the same.